# Need apache_note() function with nginx / usertrack for nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have nginx server , but need to run **apache_note()** functionality.
Is there any module , or any patch of nginx which provides this function?
Also need **usertrack** extension (which is readily available in apache) for nginx or similar alternative of it.If there is no usertrack available with nginx , please suggest some logic which emulates same functionality.

Comment: @VBart , I know thats why asking nginx alternative for it.

Comment: @VBart apache_note is really handy if you want to tug in extra bit of information on the access_log so they could be later massaged to give better insights. 

lets say you are running an ab experiment on the same url for x% of the users visiting that page, apache_note gives you the ability to reveal whether the user hit A or B without having the user pass in extra query params.

Comment: @dminer you can use response headers for the same purpose. Even more, nginx has a special module for A/B testing: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

apache_note() is a PHP function, and nginx has nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also need usertrack extension (which is readily available in apache) for nginx or similar alternative of it.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_userid_module.html

Comment: Yes , yesterday I came to know about it.Still testing that it works same like usertrack.

Comment: thanx a lot.Looks like it works.But problem is it takes one request to set coookie and from 2nd request I can get that cookie.Can I access cookie from first request itself?

Comment: It looks like you've already found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412100/not-able-to-get-uid-from-nginx-for-first-request

Answer (score 2):

I see there is an accepted answer for this, just adding to it as I guess many people including myself got here from a Google search for apache_note and Nginx.

A main reason for using apache_note is for storing something in the access log. For example a user name when you are not using Basic Authentication.

An easy way to accomplish this with PHP and Nginx is to send it as a header and log that.

PHP: `header('username: johndoe');`

Add the following to log_format in nginx.conf: `$sent_http_username`

All headers are available to the log in the form of $sent_http_HEADERNAME

Answer (score 1):

I also found this while searching for an NGINX alternative to apache_note(). There isn't much info on it and the only solution I have found mentioned is to just use the response headers. Alone this doesn't work for data that you don't want sent back to the user, which is the situation I am working with.

The solution I found was to use the [HttpHeadersMoreModule](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) to clear the headers before they are passed on to the user. This also clears the "$sent_http_" variables, but leaves "$upstream_http_" useable for your logs.